# apt-cache pulls from /var/lib/dpkg/status - How can I prevent this?

Tags: apt, dependencies, apt-cache

I'm attempting to compile some dependency info from an older version of Ubuntu (Artful).  Basically I've downloaded the old-release stuff by adding the following lines to my /etc/var/sources.list:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then after I do a sudo apt-get update I have those files in my /var/lib/apt/lists directory.  That's all good.  Then I move those lines to their own file that I call artful_sources.list, and run apt-cache on a package with a changed sourcefile directory:

```
apt-cache -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/artful_sources.list showpkg accountsservice > accountsservice.txt
```

When I look at the results, I see the versions from Artful, certainly, but I also see the most current version from Bionic (which I have installed on my system), which it appears to be pulling from /var/lib/dpkg/status.  I only want dependencies from Artful packages.  What gives?  What other option can I change to make apt-cache not look in the status file?

Here are the results of that example:

```
Package: accountsservice
Versions:
0.6.45-1ubuntu1 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/dpkg/status
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e

0.6.42-0ubuntu3.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/dpkg/status
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
0.6.42-0ubuntu3 (/var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/old-releases.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/dpkg/status
                  MD5: 8aeed0a03c7cd494f0c4b8d977483d7e


Reverse Depends:
  unity-settings-daemon,accountsservice 0.6.34
  mugshot,accountsservice
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0,accountsservice
  indicator-sound,accountsservice
  libaccountsservice0,accountsservice 0.6.5
  gnome-control-center,accountsservice
  gdm3,accountsservice 0.6.35
  language-selector-common,accountsservice 0.6.29-1ubuntu6
  unity-settings-daemon,accountsservice 0.6.34
  libaccountsservice0,accountsservice 0.6.5
  language-selector-common,accountsservice 0.6.29-1ubuntu6
  gnome-control-center,accountsservice
```

Etc. and so on.  In this case, 0.6.45-1ubuntu1 is currently installed on Bionic, and the other versions 0.6.42-0ubuntu3 and 3.1 are from artful and artful-updates, respectively.

Comment: ```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: Again, not looking to actually USE the packages, just want to compile a list of dependencies, without say, installing Ubuntu 17.10 and then using apt-rdepends.  The purpose of this is not a use case for Ubuntu, it's to test a binary scanner.

Comment: Any if I wanted to compile this list for all versions of Ubuntu?  Seems like a lot when all the information can simply be extracted from the text in /var/lib/apt/lists.  It would be easier for me to write a script to recursively go through the lists myself.  However I thought that was the point of the apt tools.